# How to extract data out of an object array using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

First, I'd like to apologize in advance for my approximate English (I'm French) :)

I have the following array and can't figure out how to get the data out:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'id_photo' => string '14' (length=2)
      public 'id_user' => string '40' (length=2)
      public 'titre' => string 'Ma 2e TOF Mimi' (length=14)
      public 'taille' => string '54' (length=2)
      public 'nom' => string 'debutScript.PNG' (length=15)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'id_photo' => string '12' (length=2)
      public 'id_user' => string '39' (length=2)
      public 'titre' => string 'Ma TOF Seb' (length=10)
      public 'taille' => string '16' (length=2)
      public 'nom' => string 'BDD.PNG' (length=7)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'id_photo' => string '13' (length=2)
      public 'id_user' => string '40' (length=2)
      public 'titre' => string 'Ma TOF Mimi' (length=11)
      public 'taille' => string '24' (length=2)
      public 'nom' => string 'COMMUNE.PNG' (length=11)
```

This is the result of `var_dump($res);`

I want to know how to display in the var_dump only the objects with `id_user` are equal to 40 => an array with 2 objects.
So concretely I would like to know how to access to `id_user` of every object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can iterate over the items of the array `foreach($res as $item)` and then check if the id matches your expectations: `$item->id_user >= 40`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the array as follows

```
foreach($data as $row){
   if($row->id_user == 40){
      //desired actions you want to perform
   }
}
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you that's really help me :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Please accept the answer and upvote if possible.